# Add time scale to columns in a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, dynamic

I'm developing an app that creates a timeline in run time. So I created a Grid (not a datagrid) and I wanna put some time stamps in equal spaces (60 pixels/hour - 1 pixel/minute).

I already know how to create the columns programmatically:

```
public void ColumnCreator(double totalInterval, double divPattern)
{
    int divisionPattern = Convert.ToInt16(divPattern);
    if (divisionPattern < totalInterval)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalInterval; i += divisionPattern)
        {
            internalGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { 
                Width = new GridLength(divisionPattern, GridUnitType.Pixel) });
        }
    }
}
```

but these lines are not synchronized. Does anybody have a solution for me?

Thanks in advance 8-)

Comment: You haven't really stated what you mean by "lines are not synchronized"?  Anyhow, I would not use a grid / column system for this layout. Try a Canvas, where you place the lines explicitely. See this article for ideas: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfWinFormsBulletGraphs.aspx

Comment: Thank you for answering me, I'll consider your suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out especially for *real time* visualization `Grid` may be the worse choice you can made. `Grid` is responsible for **containing controls layout management** and has a heavy impact on performance.

Use a `Canvas` to **draw** a stuff on it. Use `Shape` and `Path` for drawing. To achive a reasonable performance on real time UI you need to read at least this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx

Do not use `Pixels` but provided by WPF `Units`, which are device independent way to declaring the dimension of something in WPF. So your drawing will maintain a proportion on different monitors `screen sizes` and `dpi`.